# getUrl - getSkinUrl displaying insecure content on HTTPS pages

Tags: ssl

Visitors to my website in HTTPS are receiving messages that some of the content is not secure. Upon investigation it appears that my active template has a **getUrl** and **getSkinUrl** code that calls the home button but displays it in HTTP and not HTTPS.

```
<a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl() ?>"><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>images/Home.gif" alt="<?php echo $this->__('Home');?>"/>
```

How do I make a call to **getUrl** and **getSkinUrl** to generate secure links on secure pages?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

first of all, this:

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl(); ?>images/Home.gif
```

should be

```
<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/Home.gif'); ?>
```

You can pass parameters to getUrl to make it secure:

```
$this->getUrl('', array('_secure'=>true));
$this->getSkinUrl('images/Home.gif', array('_secure'=>true));
```

Comment: The reason for the alt was so that in a text browser "Home" will appear, I'll modify my file and report back. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Leave the alt where it is. just modify the urls

Answer (score 0):

Change the unsecure URL under:

**System > Configuration > General > Web > Unsecure**

Needs to be changed to **http://** instead of **https://**.

This fixed the issue.